# Azure DevOps Pipeline Pull Remote Server Changes

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

My Self Hosted Build Server E drive has some source files which which needs syncing with azure repos. I am managed to update the remote servers with Git Pull command however i am not able to push changes to azure repos from build server source files. I see a message head is deatcahed however if i log on to server and run git status i can see there are files to be pushed.

My question is it possible through pipeline that to push changes from build server to AzureRepos ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you understand what a "detached head" means and how to change it? If not, start there.

Comment: Maybe you could share your script/command/pipeline with which you're trying to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed this documentation which helped me achieve above.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

I created bat file in the repository with set of instructions

Given permission to pipeline

Executed on a self-hosted agent

Able to achieve the results i:e pull latest code from the server and push the changes to repository.

Comment: Please can you post more details about how you did this?